# Community Resurrection Of Answered Questions

Tags: feature-request

The system automatically bumps questions that don't have "accepted" answers to the top to the question queue every so often.

This seems like a good thing in the case of unanswered questions, but I wonder if it doesn't happen a bit too frequently in the case of answered questions, many of whom are left by users who are first time users or otherwise no longer have contact with the forum and may have never known how to accept an answer.

Should this be limited to a one time bump, or made less frequently? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The logic of the "Community ♦ user" applies to all Stack Exchange sites, so any questions about how or why; or suggestions for improving its behavior, should be raised on [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-user).

Regarding this particular question: An answer to [one recent post on this subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288004/241697) notes that it only takes a single upvote on an answer to a bumped question to get it off the *Unanswered* list.

Comment: Good to know. The SE logic is a mystery to me.